# Pandas dataframe print statement, format one row per line without index

Tags: python, pandas, io

I have a pandas dataframe of tweets extracted from a JSON file:

```
# Grab the data from internet
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://some/url/tweets.json') as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

# Convert the data into a pandas data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Select the pertinent information
df1 = df[['text','lang']]

# Print the individual tweets
tweets1 = tweets['text']
```

I now want to print a .txt file with each tweet per line. 
I tried:

```
with io.open("tweets.txt","w",encoding = 'utf8') as tweets:    
    print(tweets1, file = tweets)
```

And also:

```
with io.open("tweets.txt","w",encoding = 'utf8') as tweets:    
    print(tweets1.to_csv(header = False), file = tweets)
```

The problem is that in both cases, the individual tweets are broken across multiple lines. Moreover, the csv attempt includes a row count- which I do not want. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing it to be broken across multiple lines without some sample data. However you can concatenate a list into a string using `join`, and if you use newline as a separator, it should work as required.

```
with open("tweets.txt", "w") as tweets: 
    print('\n'.join(tweets1), file = tweets)
```

Comment: Wouldnt this begin the file with a blank line? I do not want that either

Comment: No, because join inserts a newline _between_ each item in the list (or pandas Series in this case).

Comment: Ok, but this doesnt work- it creates a file with a single line 'text' thats all.

Comment: Ah. To work, `tweets1` needs to be a pandas `Series`. In your case, it is actually a one column `DataFrame`. So join was operating on the column names. This is because you select the column using `tweets[['text']]`. If instead you used `tweets['text']`, you will have a `Series`, and it will work.

Comment: Ok, well the tweets are printing now at least. Still doesnt quite work as some of the messages are broke across multiple lines. I think part of the problem is that some of the individual tweets have new-line characters in them.

Comment: `tweets1 = tweets['text'].str.replace('\n', ' ')` might help with that, replacing newlines with a space or whatever you'd prefer.